# how do you automatically enable network interface at system startup?

Tags: networking, command-line, networkmanager, cinnamon

I have a network interface that is configured for static ip address.

When I reboot I have to always open the NetworkManager GUI and click "connect" button.

### How do you automatically enable network interface at system startup?

Answer (score 0):

### In the Cinnamon desktop manager:

- go to the taskbar
- click on the the networking icon (looks like two plugs about to be connected (think of Michelangelo's creation of Adam but with generic plugs))
- *it brings up a GUI panel right above the taskbar*
- click "network settings"
- *brings up a "Network" dialog*
- click on your network interface
- click the gear icon
- *brings up a new dialog*
- on the left is a list of text names one should be named "Identity", click on "Identity"
- on the bottom make sure the "Connect Automatically" checkbox is enabled
- done
- bonus: restart and verify the network interface comes up after a restart

### The command line method:

- disclaimer i haven't tested this method because this method uses the old `ifconfig` tools which are [deprecated since about 2014 (or if you do lots of EL work 2014 coincides with centos7 release)](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ifconfig-vs-ip#:%7E:text=ifconfig%20has%20been%20officially%20deprecated,move%20on%20with%20the%20world.&text=Since%20there%20is%20no%20%22without,IP%20addresses%20associated%20with%20interfaces.)
- get the name of the network interface
- `sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-${name_of_interface}`

  - ensure the key `ONBOOT` is present and set the value to `yes`

unfortunately these changes are not reflected in the GUI for some reason. so i do not trust this method so much and again this method depends on the deprecated `ifconfig` tools/methods. this might work but might not. the GUI method does change the value in this file so there's that.